# Creating SEO urls for resized images via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem with creating .htaccess rule for creating url for small resized images.

I have saved images inside upload/images/ directory and it looks like this:

```
somedomain.com/upload/images/bigimage-some_name123.jpg
```

I have already created url via PHP so i can call resized image:

```
somedomain.com/upload/images/small/bigimage-some_name123-150x100.jpg
```

From this small url I need 4 parameters:

- **name**: bigimage-some_name123
- **extension**: .jpg or jpg
- **width**: 150
- **height**: 100

Via .htaccess need to create url so I can fetch all parameters above and show resized image on the fly:

```
somedomain.com/image-resizer/index.php?image=upload/images/bigimage-some_name123.jpg&width=150&height=100
```

Colleague of mine send me this .htaccess line and I need to rewrite it so it can work on my project.

```
RewriteRule
^upload/images/small/([^/.]+)-([0-9]{3,5})([^/.]+)-([0-9]{2,3})x([0-9]{2,3}).jpg$
module/show_image.php?name=../files/$2$3.jpg&width=$4&height=$5 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be well handled in rewrite rules and it is much faster than doing in PHP also. You can use this rule in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(upload/images)/small/(.+?)-(\d+)x(\d+)\.(jpe?g)$ image-resizer/index.php?image=$1/$2.$5&width=$3&height=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to extract information from the path in the .htaccess rewrite rule. It's much easier doing that in PHP. So what I do is to feed the whole SEO optimized URL to the PHP page behind the rewrite rule. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?SEOPath=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

You can see how simple the rewrite rule now is. Then in PHP I work on the SEO path, and extract the wanted information, which is not too difficult.

Of course you still need to adapt this to your situation. For instance, restrict it to .jpg files only. In your case it could be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpg$ /module/your.php?SEOPath=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmmm so you basically suggest that I add route **upload/images/small/**  to my PHP code and call special controller/action to handle this action and extract image name, extension, width and height... Never thought of this before, thanks, maybe better way of doing it ;)

Comment: yes, that's the idea. It's just easier to extract the information in PHP, and your rewrite rule stays simple. PHP can also cope with variations in the path more easily than the rewrite rule, you can better debug it, and catch hacking attempts.

Comment: Think about it, what would happen to your server if someone used: 'bigimage-some_name123-15000x10000.jpg'? You need to filter the input before if gets into the core of your system.

Comment: You might want to add an additional check for whether the requested image size already exist – so that you do not have to create it on-the-fly each and every time, but only if that has not been done already. (Your script then has to store the created image in the file system as well, obviously.)

Comment: @CBroe yes, of course, there will be some sort of caching mechanism to save image that is already called via script. First check if image exists, if not then create on-the-fly

Comment: @fsasvari: The checking for existence does not need to be within the script, mod_rewrite can do that already. Check the documentation for [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), specifically the `-f` flag.